# why servlet name appending to requesting map url ? is it possible to have URL without servlet name prefix?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have servlet xml file  personDetails-servlet.xml

```
<bean>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/yyy/config/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ddd.config.controller" />
</beans>
```

And Web.xml entry

```
 <servlet>
      <servlet-name>personDetails</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>personDetails</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/personDetails/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

and below is PersonDetailsController

```
 package com.ddd.config.controller;
 @Controller
 public class PersonDetailsController {
 @RequestMapping(value="/personDetails/personAddressDetails.html",            method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public String abc(ModelMap model) throws Exception{
 }
 }
```

And i am trying to hit with http://localhost:8080/myapp/personDetails/ConfgurationDetails.html
it's not working
when i tried with below one it is working
http://localhost:8080/myapp/personDetails/personDetails/ConfgurationDetails.html

can some one tells, how i can do without adding servlet name to request mapping ulr, and also tell me how name is adding.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `web.xml` config file, you tell your application to use the `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` class to handle requests that match `<application_context>/personDetails/*`.

The previous URL is the starting point of all URLs you'll use with Spring MVC. So, if you declare the following handler `@RequestMapping(value="/personAddressDetails.html")`, then the URL you need to call will be `<application_context>/personDetails/personAddressDetails.html`.

In other words, you don't need the add the servlet mapping prefix to your Controller's `RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: hi alexandre
thanks for for reply. but i have tried this. i know it will work. but, here also it is adding servlet name prefix. But i need some solution where applicationContext/ReqestMapping  only. I have this problem multiple palces. i cant maintain url's with servlet name prefix. 

only requestmapping i need.

is it possible or not ..?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you want to get ride off the `/personDetails` part, then use `/*` as the Dispatcher' servlet mapping.

Comment: what u said , tha's rigth
need to use /* for that.
i have changed it remaining places 
thanks